# Javafx : TableCell reference

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8, tablecell

I want to get a reference to a certain cell in a `TableView`. How is this possible?
T tried `tableView.getColumns().get(0).getCellFactory()` but there isn't any method which returns a reference to a cell. So is there any way to get the cell for a certain index(e.g. cell at (1,2)(something that extends `TableCell<>()`)). It doesn't matter if via reflection or somehow, if you have any idea please tell help me.

Comment: The whole reason there exists a cell factory is that cells are able to be recycled. You could scroll down and the cell which previously represented (1,2) could now represent (1,10). Because of this, there's very little reason to want to get a specific cell. **What are you planning on doing with the cell?** If you just want the data contained within, you can use `tableView.getItems()`

Comment: I don't think that the cell changes it's indices. If I move the row or the column somehow then yes, but if I don't then I think not. I want to get its `Graphic` for example a `ComboBox` and select an item. I know I can get the items then set its value, but I want to write a test for my view and its better to have a reference to my combobox or checkbox then say, please select the third one then check it if fulfills a condition, if i say `myStringProperty().set("Apple")`. then `Assert.assertEquals("Apple",table.getItems().get(0).getMyString());` its pretty obvious that passes.

Comment: The cell can change its index at essentially an arbitrary time.

Comment: Then there is no possibility to do that I want?

Comment: I have no clue what you are actually trying to do, so I don't know if it's possible to do what you want. Typically you write a cell factory that generates cells that observe your model, then access the model to modify/access the data.

Comment: @James_D your comment helped me very much in a different, but related problem. The main idea I got from it was that the display of the data ( cell ) should e separated from the update of the data.

Comment: Given the contents of the table *will not change* you can provide a custom cellfactory in which the returned cell is also stored in a List independent of the TableView. This way the list can be queried for the references, and the factories can be used to pupulate the list with them.